# How specific must a contract be?

Tags: business

"There is no refunds with this purchase. If you are a mentor or are affiliated with any other trade teams you will be removed and will not be refunded if found. Legal action will be taken on any members that share our content. Vertex Investing are not financial advisors, Following trade ideas and trading in general does have an element of risk. Please do not risk capital you cannot afford. Vertex investing are not liable for any losses incurred."

This is what is in my terms and conditions... Someone is trying to get out of paying (of course I will be writing a proper contractual agreement after this) but how valid is my argument for having them pay?

Comment: This seems like something you need a ask a lawyer to analyze with regard to your specific factual situation.

Comment: "*how valid is my argument for having them pay?*" What argument? Your post is unclear and too broad. There is no context about the person who "*is trying to get out of paying*". I strongly encourage you to attain a good understanding of the principles of contract law, which are formulated in resources such as the [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html), and reading court opinions. That will prepare you for drafting, analyzing, and entering actual contracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does  not say what reasons the other party gives for not paying, and so one cannot judge whether such reason is covered by the terms quoted in the question.

In general a contract need not be highly specific if the intent is clear. However, any ambiguity  will usually be resolved against the party who wrote the contract, so it is in that party's interest to be as clear and specific as possible.

It is not clear from the quoted terms that they form a contract at all. No consideration is stated.

Contractual provisions which deny all recourse are not always enforceable. They may be overruled by law or regulation, or by prior court decision or by an equitable decision. If there is a serious problem with the service provided, particularly in a consumer transaction, a court might reject a provision denying all refunds even if it is quite specific and clear.

The question does not list the jurisdiction (country and, for federal countries, state or province). Laws on contracts  and enforceable terms vary significantly  in different jurisdictions. Without this a specific answer is not possible.